# I'm getting a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'" error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I execute the following code:

```
USE Database
GO

DECLARE @DF Datetime = CONVERT(datetime,'30/01/2017',103)
DECLARE @DT Datetime = CONVERT(datetime,'13/03/2017',103)

DECLARE @Owner nvarchar(255) = 'user@email.co.uk'
DECLARE @Box nvarchar(255) = 'Sent Items'
DECLARE @ResultTo int = 0
DECLARE @ResultCC int = 0
DECLARE @ResultBCC int = 0

SET @ResultTo = COUNT(ToEmailAddress) FROM EmailTo 
WHERE fkDataExtractTableID IN 
    (
        SELECT DataExtractTableID
        FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataExtractTable]
        WHERE (DateSent between @DF AND @DT)
        AND ([Owner] = @Owner)
        AND (Box = @Box)
      )
```

I get this error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Because you're trying to use `SET` with regular `SELECT` syntax. It should be either `SET @ResultTo = (SELECT COUNT(ToEmailAddress)...)` OR `SELECT @ResultTo = COUNT(ToEmailAddress)...`

Comment: Strangely I did write it originally with brackets around everything to the right of the = sign but was still getting an error, but I have got it working now thanks to the comments here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is the corrected one:

```
DECLARE @DF Datetime = CONVERT(datetime,'30/01/2017',103)
DECLARE @DT Datetime = CONVERT(datetime,'13/03/2017',103)

    DECLARE @Owner nvarchar(255) = 'user@email.co.uk'
    DECLARE @Box nvarchar(255) = 'Sent Items'
    Declare @ResultTo int = 0
    Declare @ResultCC int = 0
    Declare @ResultBCC int = 0

    SELECT @ResultTo = COUNT(ToEmailAddress) FROM EmailTo 
    WHERE fkDataExtractTableID IN 
    (
        SELECT DataExtractTableID
        FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataExtractTable]
        WHERE (DateSent between @DF AND @DT)
        AND ([Owner] = @Owner)
        AND (Box = @Box)
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, certainly it fixes the syntax error.  I have three of these routines that get email data from linked tables and I am trying to store the result for TO, CC and BCC emails as a number and then return that number to the caller so somewhere at the bottom I will have returnVal = ResultTo + ResultCC + resultBCC.  Although your syntax works how do I return the final total as a query result as this just gives a message saying it has completed successfully but no result is displayed? (had to remove at signs as system won't let me post with the at signs left in).

Comment: OK I figured it myself I just do:

Select ATResult as Result

At the end (the AT being the symbol).

Answer (score 0):

I think your sql wrong on line 12. It may be like this:

```
SET @ResultTo = (select COUNT(ToEmailAddress) FROM EmailTo)
```

Comment: Thanks this and other comments above have helped me get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable assignment to:

```
select @ResultTo = count(ToEmailAddress) from EmailTo
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have it sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 2 different syntax in a select query. Either use `Set` statement or use simple query

**Set Statement - where you set a single variable as a return from a select query**

```
SET @ResultTo = (Select COUNT(ToEmailAddress) FROM EmailTo 
WHERE fkDataExtractTableID IN 
    (
        SELECT DataExtractTableID
        FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataExtractTable]
        WHERE (DateSent between @DF AND @DT)
        AND ([Owner] = @Owner)
        AND (Box = @Box)
      ) )
```

**Or Select statement where you set multiple variables value like**

```
Select @ResultTo = COUNT(ToEmailAddress)  
--Aslo define other variable, if you want
-- like @ResultTo1 , but this query is aggregation, so only aggeregate function use
FROM EmailTo 
WHERE fkDataExtractTableID IN 
    (
        SELECT DataExtractTableID
        FROM [Database].[dbo].[DataExtractTable]
        WHERE (DateSent between @DF AND @DT)
        AND ([Owner] = @Owner)
        AND (Box = @Box)
      )
```